# immediate shutdown at boot time with 8GB memory

Tags: boot, ram

PC: VersaPro(VK24LX-B)

OS: ubuntu 15.10

Today I went a PC shop to upgrade memory from 4GB to 8GB, but the staff told me he couldn't do that.He demonstrated what happened:

Changing memory cards, turning on my PC, then the monitor showed GRUB menu.
After he chose a menu item named "*ubuntu", the monitor showed a few lines, which I can't remember exactly but the output was that the file system was recovering journal or something, then the PC suddenly shutdown.

I never have encountered that situations before.

He also checked BIOS: it showed 8GB RAM was recognized.

So next he did memtest86+, but it looked crushed(graphic got collapsed and nothing happened) after a few seconds since it started.

Finally he changed memory cards back to 4GB and that perfectly worked (OS normally booted up and I could login).

We didn't have any idea to solve this problem, so I got back home.

Are there any check points I should try to make sure what/where is wrong?

---

```
$ LANG=C lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 37
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU       M 370  @ 2.40GHz
Stepping:              5
CPU MHz:               933.000
CPU max MHz:           2399.0000
CPU min MHz:           933.0000
BogoMIPS:              4787.42
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              3072K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

```
$ uname -a
Linux hello-goodbye 4.2.0-30-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 19 13:52:26 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ sudo dmidecode -t memory

# dmidecode 2.12
SMBIOS 2.6 present.

Handle 0x0029, DMI type 16, 15 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 8 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 2

Handle 0x002A, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0029
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 2048 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM1
    Bank Locator: Not Specified
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1066 MHz
    Manufacturer: 04CB
    Serial Number: 00007575
    Asset Tag: Unknown
    Part Number:                   
    Rank: Unknown

Handle 0x002C, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0029
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 2048 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM2
    Bank Locator: Not Specified
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1066 MHz
    Manufacturer: 0000
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: Unknown
    Part Number: EE7YG1B1674EU     
    Rank: Unknown
```

please tell me what else information is needed to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for several hours, I gave up to solve this problem because it is more likely that this is a kind of problems of chipsets and memory cards, not ubuntu itself.

And my PC looks too old to find memory cards that fit to it.

The PC maker(NEC) that also offered memory cards for their products has stopped to make the proper memory cards that is tested.

It is understandable that memory cards that is made today doesn't work on the chipset which was made 5 years ago. It's possible.